# sum of all values in column in array based on column value from other array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of user info in `@user_info` and in array there is a column `total` and column `user_id`.

I have another instance variable `@product` and it has column `user_id`

How do i calculate sum of all values in column `total` verifying the `user_id` from `@user_info` and `@product` same?

I am trying to calcuate sum in controller, store it in instance variable and use that variable in JSON

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
@user_info.select { |user_info| user_info.user_id == @product.user_id }.sum(&:total)
```

or, if `@user_info` is not a simple `Array`, you should be able to do in one SQL query

```
@user_info.where(user_id: @product.user_id).sum(:total)
```

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)